# System.Drawing.Drawing2d not recognized under Framework 4.5 Project

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, frameworks

I've Created a C# CLass Library with Framework 4.5 , I've referenced System.Drawing ,
The project can not recognize classes like Bitmap, Image or Rectangle.

I can not add a reference to System.Drawing.Drawing2d because it does not exits. (Under References >Add Reference > In Framework Section)

also the Intellisense can not recognize the appropriate Class for Image or Bitmap.

What could be the solution ?

Comment: Small sample code (including `using` part and how you try to use `System.Drawing.Bitmap`)  would help to understand problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply System.Drawing.  There is no drawing2d assembly.

Comment: I don't know why , but deleting the Class Library and creating a new same one , solved my problem